# JQuery can you show a different element on each subsequent click?

Tags: jquery

I have a really simple idea... have a button (class="upload") that on each subsequent click, I want it to show a new div, for a set maximum number of times.

For example:

```
$('.upload').click(function() {
            $('.upload_block2').show(0);
        }, function() {
            $('.upload_block3').show(0);
        }, function() {
            $('.upload_block4').show(0);
        }, function() {
            $('.upload_block5').show(0);
            $('.upload').hide(0);
        });
```

Obviously the code above does not work...

Is this even possible?

Comment: You could use a counter.  So long as the page isn't refreshed, it should be retained.  Not sure if you're wanting it to persist through page refreshes.

Comment: @Thecor it doesn't need to persist through page refreshes... can I ask what the counter would look like? I tried one but failed miserably

Comment: Moishe posted it below. That should work. However, if you want it to go back to the first upload after 5, you would need to check for cutrentblock=5, then set set currentblock back to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare two global variables, one for the total number of blocks to show, another for the current block that is shown.

When `.upload` is clicked on, check `currentBlock < maxBlock`. If it is, increment the current block that should be shown and concatenate `.upload_block` with `currentBlock` to get the jquery selector.

```
var maxBlock = 5;
var currentBlock = 1;
$('.upload').click(function() {
    if(currentBlock < maxBlock) {
        currentBlock ++;
        $('.upload_block'  + currentBlock).show(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will work for you.

```
$('.upload').toggle(function() {
        $('.upload').hide(0);
        $('.upload_block2').show(0);
    }, function() {
        $('.upload').hide(0);
        $('.upload_block3').show(0);
    }, function() {
        $('.upload').hide(0);
        $('.upload_block4').show(0);
    }, function() {
        $('.upload').hide(0);
        $('.upload_block5').show(0);
});
```

Refere: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_toggle.asp

Comment: I think this logic is best, b'coz you can handle different logic in each function if you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var count = 1;
$('.upload').click(function(){
    $(body).append('<div id="Div'+count+'"></div>');
    count++;
});
```

This will append a new div every time with a unique id also.